# Importing mixed column as numeric using proc import from excel in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to import an excel sheet with the

```
proc import datafile="...." out=data2 dbms=xlsx;
run;
```

But the problem is I am getting many variables are CHAR datatype in SAS which were of numeric in excel. How can I get the same data type that are there as of in excel sheet?

Comment: By default it should import numeric columns as numeric. Are you sure that values in those excel columns are all numeric and not mixed?

Comment: they can be mixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When SAS is importing excel file it is scanning data in columns to determine what type should be assigned to new column in SAS. By default it scans data and if mixed data is found then assigns character data type. Try setting option `MIXED=NO` like this.

```
proc import datafile="...." out=data2 dbms=xlsx;
    mixed=no;
run;
```